# Specify drive letter to use while attaching virtual disk (.vhd) programmatically

Tags: winapi, virtual, vhd

I am using [`OpenVirtualDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`AttachVirtualDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions to mount VHD files, but I couldn't find how to specify a drive letter while mounting the vhd file.

I would like to specify the drive letter for e.g (G:, H:, K: etc) to mount.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but probably by attaching it without a drive letter first (see flags) and then calling `SetVolumeMountPoint` or `DefineDosDevice` yourself. Both allow you to pass in the desired drive letter. (Which of course carries a race condition. Even if you thought the drive letter was free, it may not be once you call SetVolumeMountPoint)